# Using SimpleModal JS to create a modal to fill the browser window.

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm using the [Simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) JQuery plugin in a project of mine. I'm trying to make the modal fill the full browser window though and seem to be having trouble. Setting the modal containers width and height to 100% explicitly from with in CSS does not see to be doing the trick.

I'm trying using the `minWidth` and `minHeight`options as well but that is still not working out. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `modal` with explicit css params passed:

```
$('#basicModalContent').modal({containerCss: {left: 0, top: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%'}});
```

Comment: I wonder if 100% works. If not, try:  `width: $(window).width()`

Comment: If this works that would be great, although since they give you default options that only accepts pixel values I'm wondering if this method will target the div that wraps $('#basicModalContent')

Comment: Yeah, I doubt '%' would work, because of what you said -- parameter only accepts a number. $(window).width() will return a number, so I'm guessing that should work.

Comment: Oops, sorry. To work properly It should look like this: `$('#basicModalContent').modal({containerCss: {left: 0, top: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%'}});`

Comment: "%" works like a charm, because containerCss object's key/value pairs just passed to jQuery css method.

Comment: `$(window).width()` is not the best solution, because in this case width of popup will be static, while user can resize browser window with popup displayed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the modal is gonna have `position: absolute`, so you won't be able to use 100% width and height to fill the viewport.

This is from the simplemodal docs:

> maxHeight [Number:null] The maximum height for the container. If not
>   specified, the window height is used.
>
> maxWidth [Number:null] The maximum width for the container. If not
>   specified, the window width is used.

So when you instantiate a simplemodal, just add a really high number for these options. It should make it fill the viewport:

```
$("#element-id").modal({
  maxHeight: 10000,
  maxWidth: 10000
})
```

If this doesn't work, you can always get the height of the viewport with $(window).height() and $(window).width(). Then you could explicitly set the modal:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('#modal-id').height( windowHeight );
```

You'd have to test all browsers, because it could look funky in some cases.

Comment: Actually, I think it defaults to a fixed position if I'm not mistaken. But thanks! Going to give this a shot.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think it's best to try to use the plugin's built-in functionality, but if it's just not working, you can change the modal dimensions pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery "modal dialog" is just a div on the page that is on top of all the other elements, usually with a semi-transparent background that covers the rest of the area. An i-frame has constrained proportions.

You may be able to reference the  parent.window, so the modal is not confined to the iframe area.

It may be easier to have some script on the parent page to execute the request.